# How to scrape a value from web page with XPath

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/120960754"
url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="is24-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/span')%>%
    html_text()
```

Full Xpath

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/span
```

The value I need to scrape sits here:

```
<span class="additional-costs-value font-ms font-semibold">13.810&nbsp;€</span>
```

Comment: I don't know R but the website is displaying that content using javascript and therefore you're probably not able get it using rvest. There's an API for this site you can request the information from easily though, you can investigate that through the network tool of chrometools.

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/baufinanzierung-api/restapi/api/financing/construction/v1.0/monthlyrate?exposeId=120960754&purchasePrice=99000&hasCourtage=true&geoCode=1276007019012&employment=EMPLOYED&amortizationRate=2&fixedNominalInterestRate=TEN_YEARS&ownFunds=19800&ignoreSmallLoanAmounts=true")`